# Artifactory not running after update, Column not found

Tags: artifactory

After updating Artifactory OOS from version 4.1.3 to 5.3.0 I am getting this error:

`{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Artifactory failed to initialize: check Artifactory logs for errors."
  } ]
}`

I replaced artifactory.war file, tomcat and bin folder, also tried replacing misc folder and nothing changed.
here is my artifactory.log file :
`[art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:94) - Application could not be initialized: Column '19' not found.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:211) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.access$1(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:177) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:90) ~[artifactory-web-application-5.3.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.InternalSecurityService'.; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:230) ~[artifactory-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:114) ~[artifactory-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getBoolean(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.dao.UserGroupsDao.userFromResultSet(UserGroupsDao.java:509) ~[artifactory-storage-db-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.dao.UserGroupsDao.findUserByName(UserGroupsDao.java:344) ~[artifactory-storage-db-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.dao.UserGroupsDao.findUserByName(UserGroupsDao.java:326) ~[artifactory-storage-db-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.UserGroupStoreServiceImpl.findUser(UserGroupStoreServiceImpl.java:157) ~[artifactory-storage-db-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.security.service.UserGroupStoreServiceImpl.findUser(UserGroupStoreServiceImpl.java:151) ~[artifactory-storage-db-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.findUser(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.createDefaultAnonymousUser(SecurityServiceImpl.java:2296) ~[artifactory-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.artifactory.security.SecurityServiceImpl.init(SecurityServiceImpl.java:239) ~[artifactory-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76) ~[artifactory-storage-common-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.init(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:228) ~[artifactory-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.artifactory.storage.db.util.ResultSetWrapper.invoke(ResultSetWrapper.java:75) ~[artifactory-storage-db-5.3.0.jar:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column '19' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.newSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.getColumn(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.getBoolean(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Column '19' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.11.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 50 common frames omitted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the trouble ticket they have in release notes there is a known issue.  You need to add the column

ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN credentials_expired SMALLINT

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14279